# Eclipse Marketplace: Spring Tool Suite not showing up?

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-marketplace

I'm learning Spring Boot using a [Udemy tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-boot-complete-guide-from-development-to-deployment/), which skips how to install Spring tools to our IDE, so I've been Googling how to do it myself.

There appears to be [2 options](https://dzone.com/articles/springide-using-spring-eclipse): (1) download the Spring Tool Suite 4, which comes with a new version of Eclipse and the Spring tools preinstalled, or, (2) add Spring Tool Suite to my existing Eclipse via searching the Marketplace.

I want to add it to my existing Eclipse Jee Oxygen IDE, as I have other langs and tools installed on it and I want to keep it all in the one place.

I've tried searching for it via the Marketplace wizard in Eclipse, but it doesn't appear.

I've also tried the "Drag & Drop" method using Eclipse.com's [marketplace subdomain](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4), and it just opens a new Marketplace wizard without any search parameters.

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Is there another way I can add the tools to my existing Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oxygen is the 2018 release, and is not one of the supported versions for that Marketplace entry.
2020-12 (4.18), 2020-09 (4.17), and 2020-06 (4.16) are what it lists, which is why it comes up empty when the wizard tries to load it---there's no compatible version of STS4 listed for Oxygen.

Get the current version, [2020-12](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-12/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-developers), or try to update your existing install using the Update Site https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest, then try it again.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I wasn't aware that some plugins (like Spring Tool Suite 4) would simply not show up in the marketplace window if they weren't supported by the installed Eclipse version. I really appreciate your answer - I deleted/reinstalled the latest Eclipse and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

STS plugin is having issue with eclipse JEE 2022-06 and 2022-12 , so its better to use eclipse 22-03 with STS plugin versions